# How do I pipe the output of mpv into FFmpeg on Linux?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to get the mpv output into FFmpeg, to utilize some mpv-exclusive shaders.

I am not sure if directly piping into FFmpeg is possible, or maybe an extra step in-between is needed.